# Maximum number of Solaris threads

Tags: c, multithreading, solaris

How is this determined - is it by the number of threads defined or the amount of memory and where can it be changed? I read somewhere each thread is allocated by 1 mb, but not too sure.

Comment: To close voter: May I know why you're closing this as an off topic? I mean believe this is a software/programming-related question.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, 4294967294 (2^32-2).

In practice, the limit will be significantly lower due to either implicit (memory available) or explicit (task.max-lwps, project.max-lwps and zone.max-lwps tunables) limitations.

Note that the threads stack size can be adjusted using the [lwp_default_stksize](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19082-01/819-2724/chapter2-118/index.html) tunable. It is by default much lower than the 1 MB you suggest.